# Calling a function every 40 second inside a while loop

Tags: c, timer

This code invokes a function for every 40 seconds inside a loop. I am doubtful about this condition:

> ```
> if ((time_left <= 0 || time_left > interval))
> ```

Is only checking `(time_left <= 0)` fine? I referred to some websites and they have also added a check for `time_left > interval`. Is this check required?

```
int print_timed_op()
{
    time_t        time_now;
    time_t        time_left;
    time_t        time_next_interval;
    int           interval = 40, hit_count =10; //40 second interval, 10 times
    time_next_interval = time(0) + interval;

   //tight loop
   while (1) {
         sleep(1);
         time_now = time(0);
         time_left = time_next_interval - time_now;
         /* here time_left > interval check required ? */
         if ((time_left <= 0 || time_left > interval)) { 
              call_my_fuc();
              time_next_interval = time(0) + interval;
              time_left = interval;
              hit_count--;
         }

         if(hit_count< 0)
            break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note: I don't want to use a Linux timer system call or any other method to invoke the function periodically.

Comment: How important is performance to you? In many cases `||` is slower than `|`.

Comment: performance is not an issue. precision in second also fine.

Comment: Are you wanting to call the function every 40 seconds, or to call it 40 seconds after the last call completed? They aren't necessarily the same thing (what happens if the function takes 10 seconds to execute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a fairly straightforward implementation with reasonable naming. It seems very maintainable, so good work there. Here are a few suggestions:

## Useless variables

The `time_now` variable doesn't seem to serve much of a purpose. You calculate it, then immediately use it. However, you could just call `time(0)` directly like this:

```
time_left = time_next_interval - time(0);
```

It's fewer characters, and since you're calling `time(0)` directly in several other places, any reader of the code will already have to know what it means.

## Don't Repeat Yourself

Usually the "Don't Repeat Yourself" suggestion has to do with code being copied several times. You haven't done that, but you are running your loop far more frequently than you have to. Instead of sleeping for 1 second and then checking if you've reached your desired time, why not sleep for the desired amount of time? Something like this:

```
time_t remainder = interval;
while(1)
{
    sleep(remainder);
    start_time = time(0);
    call_my_func();
    hit_count--;

    if(hit_count< 0)
        break;
    remainder = (start_time + interval) - time(0);
}
```

## Use Your Loop Counter as a Loop Counter

You have a loop control variable, but you aren't directly using it as such. Instead you've written an infinite loop and then a conditional which checks the loop counter and breaks out of the infinite loop. This isn't the 1970s! We have proper control flow structures now. Just do:

```
while (hit_count >= 0)
{
    //... etc.
    hit_count--;
}
```